# change redis timeout with puppet

Tags: redis, timeout, vagrant, puppet

I have a virtual machine which gets [redis](https://github.com/thomasvandoren/puppet-redis) installed using vagrant/puppet. How can I override/configure redis timeout setting?

Trying

```
class { 'redis':
  version => '2.6.5',
  redis_timeout => 0
}
```

gives me

```
Invalid parameter redis_timeout at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:308 on node precise64
```

I mention that I do not want two intances (one of them having the right timeout)...

```
redis::instance { 'redis-6900':
  redis_port => '6900',
  redis_timeout => 0,
}
```

... or changing the original configuration params file from the module

```
# == Class: redis::params
#
# Redis params.
#
# === Parameters
#
# === Authors
#
# Thomas Van Doren
#
# === Copyright
#
# Copyright 2012 Thomas Van Doren, unless otherwise noted.
#
class redis::params {

  $redis_port = '6379'
  $redis_bind_address = false
  $version = '2.4.13'
  $redis_src_dir = '/opt/redis-src'
  $redis_bin_dir = '/opt/redis'
  $redis_max_memory = '4gb'
  $redis_max_clients = false
  $redis_timeout = 0         # 0 = disabled
  $redis_loglevel = 'notice'
  $redis_databases = 16
  $redis_slowlog_log_slower_than = 10000 # microseconds
  $redis_slowlog_max_len = 1024
  $redis_password = false

}
```

Comment: Should not happen. Can you check your `modules/redis/init.pp` for the `$redis_timeout` parameter to class `redis`? It's there on github, so it would not make sense for Puppet to report this error. Make sure there is no other `class redis` defined anywhere.

Comment: so the `reds_timeout` is set to the default value, 300. I want to change this without modifying the original module files, which are versioned. It works fine if I do it, and I took this solution for now